# InputStream to Observable leaks

Tags: java, c#, android, performance, xamarin.android

I want to view `top` metrics live in a Xamarin.Android application.
I have this code to read `top` and bind the results to a view.

```
public IObservable<GlobalMetric> GetCpuLive(CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
        {
            var pid = Process.MyPid();

            var p = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec($"top -p {pid} -m 15 -d 1");
            var streamReader = new Java.IO.InputStreamReader(p.InputStream);
            cancellationToken?.Register(() => p.Destroy());

            return Observable.Create<GlobalMetric>(async (observer, token) =>
            {
                using (var reader = new Java.IO.BufferedReader(streamReader))
                {
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
                        var match = Regex.Match(line, $"{pid}\\s+.*");
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            var splitted = match.Value.Split(" ").Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e)).ToList();
                            double.TryParse(splitted[8], out var cpu);
                            double.TryParse(splitted[9], out var memory);
                            observer.OnNext(new GlobalMetric()
                            {
                                Cpu = cpu,
                                Memory = memory
                            });
                        }

                        line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    }
                }

                await p.WaitForAsync();
            });
        }
```

It works perfectly (haven't tested the cancellation though..) but when I attach the Xamarin Profiler I notice that my string allocations are growing.

Anybody have any ideas how to handle this better?
I've tried `Exec` `top` with `-n 1` and use an interval for the observable but the CPU doesn't like it...

Comment: strings get recreated every time they get changed; partly why StringBuilder is a pretty useful component and it's obviously available in Xamarin. Might be worth considering, or alternatively take a look at this article and see if it helps: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/creating-strings-with-no-allocation-overhead-using-string-create-csharp

Comment: Thanks, great article! Though not really helpful in this context.